# Enums as Request Parameters in Spring Boot Rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I am new to spring boot and trying to use Enum as a parameter of a rest request.

This is my Enum class:

```java
public enum Month {

    JANUARY (1, "january"), FEBRUARY(2,"february"), MARCH(3,"march"),
    APRIL(4,"april"), MAY(5,"may"), JUNE(6,"june"), JULY(7,"july"),
    AUGUST(8, "august"), SEPTEMBER(9,"september"), OCTOBER(10,"october"),
    NOVEMBER(11,"november"), DECEMBER(12,"december");

    private String desc;
    private int id;

    //Constructure

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

In my controller class I am using this method:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testmonth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Month TestForMonth(@RequestBody Month inputPayload) {
            Month response = inputPayload;
            response.setId(inputPayload.getId());
            response.setDesc(inputPayload.getDesc());
            System.out.println("As String: " + inputPayload.getDesc() + ". As int " + inputPayload.getId() + ".");
            return response;
        }
```

This is my JSON:

```
{
    Month: "JANUARY"
}
```

But it is not working.. I am getting this error:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.simplerestapis.models.Month` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.simplerestapis.models.Month` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

Comment: It looks like malformed request body. I presume that your request is not a json. Try to post something like "JANUARY" (with quotation marks).

Comment: Please also add the JSON payload of your request.

Comment: @Arnaud i did thanks for letting me know.

Comment: try only "JANUARY" without braces

Comment: @merdle My pleasure :) I posted it as an answer so you can vote on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body is declared as simple enum type, not object. So instead of posting JSON object with braces try to post only a value, which is for example:

```
"JANUARY"
```